# Is the 7-clue 6x6 Sudoku solvable?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

So I was trying to find an 8-clue 6x6 Sudoku because I knew from [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257909952_Minimal_number_of_clues_for_Sudokus) paper that only 8 clues were needed to create a 6x6 Sudoku with a unique solution.

However, I have managed to find one with 7 clues:

[image]

Or, if you're like me and prefer it with 2x3 boxes:

[image]

While I am aware that this is supposed to be played as a [Sixy Sudoku](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343345/number-of-solutions-and-minimal-clues-in-sixy-sudoku), what I would like to know is if it is actually solvable as a normal 6x6 Sudoku or not.

This is the progress I have made so far:

> [image]

> What I have done to make progress on the Sudoku is if there is no real way to tell which number goes in which cell, I type the numbers that can go there, and then use process of elimination to remove possibilities until there is only one number left. (no guesswork involved)

---

However, my question is:

### Is the 7-clue 6x6 Sudoku solvable from here, or is it only possible to solve it as a Sixy Sudoku?

Comment: You can remove a 5 from one of the cells (obvious, or a typo).

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry about that, that is a typo. Thanks for catching it though. :)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "solvable".  Do you mean "there is at least one solution"? Or a unique solution? Or "it can it be solved by deduction alone, without guessing?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is...

> ...not uniquely solvable.  There are 281 solutions.

Here are two:

> ```
>  5 2 6 4 3 1    1 2 6 4 3 5
>  1 4 3 6 2 5    5 4 3 6 2 1
>  4 5 1 3 6 2    4 5 1 3 6 2
>  3 6 2 1 5 4    3 6 2 1 5 4
>  2 3 4 5 1 6    2 3 4 5 1 6
>  6 1 5 2 4 3    6 1 5 2 4 3
> ```

Notice that some of your progress is too strong.  In fact, it turns out that...

> ...only the 7 given cell values are uniquely determined.  That is, for all other cells, there is more than one possible value among the 281 solutions.